# Hibernate one-to-many relationship java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'person_id' cannot be null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new to hibernate, learn doc save persistent object

followed [hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap)  this is person and phone relationship one-to-many

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class Phone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Person person;

  //omit setter and getter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
   //omit getter and setter 
}
```

I'm persistent person and add one phone the error be throw

```
@Test
public void say() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setUsername("aaaa");

    Phone phone = new Phone();
    phone.setNumber("111");

    person.getPhones().add(phone);

    personService.save(person);
}
```

this is Dao persistent

```
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void save(Person person) {
        entityManager.persist(person);
}
```

Update service code, service just save person

```
@Service(value = "personService")
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void save(Person person) {
        personDao.save(person);
    }
}
```

error info:

```
    23:35:47.059 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
23:35:47.062 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    insert 
    into
        phone
        (number, person_id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
23:35:47.297 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a]
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'person_id' cannot be null
```

[image: erro img info]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `@GeneratedValue` annotation to specify that the primary key for both entities will be populated outside of your code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;

    @JoinColumn("person_id")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Person person;

  //omit setter and getter
}


public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
   //omit getter and setter 
}
```

Additionally, you need to persist the `Person` object instead of the `Phone` object because there is no cascade configured from `Phone` to `Person`.  If you can't do that, switch the `CascadeType` on `Person` to none and put the cascade on the `Phone` as shown above.

You should also add a `@JoinColumn` annotation on the `Phone` entity so hibernate is aware of the foreign key column.

Comment: after do it add  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) for both entity, still get Column 'person_id' cannot be null, it's strange

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: database is mysql 8.0.13

Comment: There is no Cascade from phone to person, persist the person, not the phone.

Comment: change person also add cascade to phone that can't work. only pass is `phone.setPerson(person)` will be work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184156/discussion-between-f-and-kevin-bowersox).

Answer (score 1):

You Missed something. You can try with this.

Person Entity

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }
    //omit getter and setter
}
```

Phone Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
public class Phone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Person person;

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //ommit setter and getter
}
```

Phone Dao

```
public interface PhoneDao {
    public Phone save(Phone phone);
}
```

PhoneDaoImpl

```
@Repository
public class PhoneDaoImpl implements PhoneDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Phone save(Phone phone) {

        return entityManager.merge(phone);
    }
}
```

PersonDaoImpl

```
@Repository
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Person save(Person person) {

        return entityManager.merge(person);
    }
}
```

Test Method

```
@Test
    @Transactional
    @Commit
    public void say()
    {
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        phone.setNumber("jghjkhk");

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setUsername("7576");

        phone.setPerson(person);
        Phone pers = phoneDao.save(phone);
        Assert.assertNotNull(pers);
    }
```

Try now. It will work.

Comment: @transactional, oh yes, have added it on service

Comment: can't work. may phone should add `phone.setPerson(person)` add ref ?

Comment: you need to id field of both table is auto increment in database and can use merge() instead of persist()

Comment: save error by merge(). phone not ref person so phone can't get person_id

Comment: Person(id,username) Phone(id,number,person_id(FK)) is it your table structure? then do it as I share. I tested this code is working

Comment: I'm not create foreign key constraint on phone table. only give person_id 

Comment: need some else configuration ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184158/discussion-between-flopcoder-and-f).

Comment: no no you have to create foreign key. Otherwise it will not work. Thats why you are getting error. Add foreign key and then write code that I shared It will work for sure

Comment: Add foreign key and then write code that I shared It will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set the value of the person->id and then also use an getter method to pass the id to your phone object instead of passing the person object

Answer (score 0):

Normally people have hibernate set the id of an entity automatically with a surrogate key.

```
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue   // should pick an appropriate strategy here
    private long id;
```

Since you don't have that you must either add it or set it yourself.

```
 Person p = new Person();
 p.setId(1);   // hopefully unique
```

The same goes for phone.

Comment: must give bi-directional person and phone would be save ? 

Comment: No, you can simply save a phone to an existing person by setting a valid person (with id) into the phone and executing em.persist(phone). In above example the phone is saved by person because of the cascade.

Comment: manual set person id can saved, but like above operation. I'm seeing log phone not ref phone so get person_id is null, may is cascade error ?

Comment: yes. create that table struct. but can't create foreign key constraint only create person_id on phone table

Answer (score 0):

As you are not having any generation type on your @Id and id is the primary key which can not be null so either you have to set value of id or have @GeneratedValue annotation on your id field and set strategy either as Auto or Identity.

You can also have your own sequence generation.

Also, you need to do same for the Phone class.